# Is there a numpy-way of taking all pairwise differences along the axis of a given array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering if there is a way to get all the possible differences of two vectors v,w along a given numpy axis?  For example, getting all differences along the last axis?

I.e. what I am searching for is a numpy-implementation of the following for loop:

```
data = np.random.normal(size=(100,10,50))

out = np.zeros((data.shape[0],data.shape[1],data.shape[1],data.shape[2]))

for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    for j in range((data.shape[1])):
        out[:,i,j,:] = data[:,i,:]-data[:,j,:]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), is the preferred choice.

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def diff(data):

  out = np.zeros((data.shape[0],data.shape[1],data.shape[1],data.shape[2]))

  for i in range(data.shape[1]):
      for j in range((data.shape[1])):
          out[:,i,j,:] = data[:,i,:] - data[:,j,:]

  return out
```

---

```
diff(data)
```

---

or you might use, numpy's broadcasting, is less efficient, but usually works.

```
a = np.transpose(data, axes=[0, 2, 1])

a = a[..., None, :] - a[..., None]
a = np.transpose(a, axes=[0, 3, 2, 1])
```